# Find a value in array with JavaScript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a Array with some datas. I want to check if a number is available in this.

Here is my array:

```js
var rooms = { "datas": [{"ID": "001"}, {"ID": "002"}, {"ID": "003"}, {"ID": "004}] };

var isPresent = false;
$.each(rooms, function(i,v){
    if(rooms[i].id == "001".id){
        isPresent = true;
        alert("Yes! Available :-)");
    }
});
if(!isPresent){
    rooms.push(newObject);
    alert("Doo! Not available");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Every time I get a true back. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `"001".id` ? You are probably comparing `undefined == undefined`

Comment: What exactly you want to compare?

Comment: You are not even looping over the correct info. Learn to debug, console.log and debugger is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Few things I noticed that when fixed make your code run fine.

You are missing a " in your data.

You need to iterate the `datas` array, but you are iterating the `rooms` obj instead.

Inside the iteration you aren't using the current value `v` and you are accessing the incorrect property `id` instead of `ID`

and then you are accessing a property of a String which you shouldn't do

```js
var rooms = { "datas": [{"ID": "001"}, {"ID": "002"}, {"ID": "003"}, {"ID": "004"}] };

var isPresent = false;
$.each(rooms.datas, function(i,v){
    if(v.ID == "001"){
        isPresent = true;
        alert("Yes! Available :-)");
    }
});
if(!isPresent){
    rooms.push(newObject);
    alert("Doo! Not available");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple mistakes here

- `"001".id` will always return `undefined`
- You are never setting `isPresent` to `false`
- `rooms[i].id`  will also return undefined since `roomss` values doesn't have `id` property

Use `find`

```
var rooms = { "datas": [{"ID": "001"}, {"ID": "002"}, {"ID": "003"}, {"ID": "004"}] };
var roomToFind = "001";
var alertMsg = !!rooms.datas.find( s => s.ID == roomToFind ) ? "Yes" : "No";
alert( alertMsg );
```

**Demo**

```js
var rooms = { "datas": [{"ID": "001"}, {"ID": "002"}, {"ID": "003"}, {"ID": "004"}] };
var roomToFind = "001";
var alertMsg = !!rooms.datas.find( s => s.ID == roomToFind ) ? "Yes" : "No";
alert( alertMsg );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```